# can MongoDB use a shard key's prefix for routing or does it need the entire shard key to route?

Tags: mongodb

## Background:

Environment:

- MongoBD 4.2
- Shards: 10
- Shard Key: {**domain**: 1, **email**: 1, **objecttype**: 1}

Data Description:

- **domain** cardinality is about 300
- **email** cardinality is about 100k (not evenly distributed over domain. one domain may have 30k emails)
- **objecttype** cardinality: 10 types (eg, 'file', 'message', 'notifcation' etc)

## Question:

1. If I have a query that contains just {domain: 'foo.com', email: 'user@foo.com'}, will mongos be able to determine which subset of shards to query?  Or will it query against all shards?
2. If it can intelligently route the request for #1, would it also work for a query like {domain: 'foo.com', objecttype: 'file'}  (where it skips the email field)

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Maybe.  It depends on where the chunk boundaries lie.
The mongos can determine that the domain-email pair "foo.com-user@foo.com" only exists on 1 shard, then it can target just that shard, but if that user has been especially prolific and has enough objects that there is a chunk on every shard with that domain-email combination, every shard will need to participate.

Q2: No. Since the mongos will have no way to determine ahead of time which emails will be associated with each objecttype, it will have to treat the email as a wildcard and submit the query to all shards.

**Edit**
As pointed out in the comments, if chunks that contain the domain only exist on a subset of the shards, scenario 2 can limit this to a domain search the same as if the query had been `{domain: 'foo.com'}`

Comment: for Q2, I have been doing some very basic tests, and it does seem to direct queries to a single shard and not go to all the shards.  I'm trying to find an example chunk that has a domain+email combination that spans 2 shards, but doesn't look like i have any in my sample data set.  But if mongos is smart enough to answer the the query from Q1, i guess it could limit the the shards based on just the domain.

Comment: I was able to make the dataset large enough to create chunks that span both shards.  For queries that have results in those chunks, the explain() results show a SHARDING_MERGE stage.. If the query doesn't have results in chunks across shards, then it does SINGLE_SHARD requests.  So basically, it seems like mongos is doing things smartly.